# Win-API MDI несколько вопросов

Tags: winapi, c#, c, c++

Здравствуйте.

Надо написать приложение на WinAPI MDI окна. Есть 2 вопроса:

1. Каким методом правильно вычислить активное окно? (Пробовал и `WM_SETFOCUS`, и `WM_MDIACTIVATE`, в теле через через `WM_MDIGETACTIVE` пытался найти активное окно, но если окна 2, то при переключении видится 2 активных.)
2. Как узнать, был ли изменен файл, который я открыл? Есть ли в `OpenFileName` или в структуре MDI флаги, отвечающие на такое требование?

Спасибо заранее за ответы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Возвращает HWND окна, в котором пользователь в данный момент работает.

```
HWND WINAPI GetForegroundWindow(void);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633505(v=vs.85).aspx

Функция GetActiveWindow извлекает оконный дескриптор активного окна, связанного с потоком, который вызывает функцию.

```
HWND GetActiveWindow(VOID)
```

http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/winapi/keyb/r.php?26

2) "Был ли изменён" - относительно чего? Это известоно только Вашей программе.
Скорее всего можно получить дату последнего изменения и сравнить с сохранённой последней датой в Вашей программе.

```
BOOL WINAPI GetFileTime(
  _In_       HANDLE hFile,
  _Out_opt_  LPFILETIME lpCreationTime,    // время создания файла
  _Out_opt_  LPFILETIME lpLastAccessTime,  // время последнего обращения к файлу
  _Out_opt_  LPFILETIME lpLastWriteTime    // время последней модификации
);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633505(v=vs.85).aspx

Есть вариант хранить хэш файла в программе, тогда всё очень просто проверяется.
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220046/how-to-get-the-md5-hash-of-a-file-in-c